# Flex to HTML5 - what for presentation layer (canvas, div, ???)

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

My question is about migration from Flex3 to HTML5. I want do migrate myself not application actually. The question is, what direction is the best and most similar to flex knowledge. Maybe I will reimplement some custom components I already have in my flex library. I think that some of useful flex components I will have to implement myself in HTML5 - e.g. AdvancedDataGrid or Tree.

Now I can see 2 possibilities:

- assume page (or big DIV) as application master class, and implement
  other components based on extending DIV functionality - and placing
  DIV in DIV in DIV - like AS3 uses UIComponent. It gives me supported
  by browser environment event handling or DIV movement and redrawing
  etc.
- assume one CANVAS component as application master class. Build own
  classes tree with owner drawing control etc. I think i will need to
  implement event handling & dispatching for my internal visual
  components. Also all UI actions (like moving, redrawing) I need to
  implement myself.

I assume, that I will start to build my own class/component library for long-term future use. Question is what is better for knowledge and work investing?

It will be good to know wide opinion on this problem. 
Can you give yours here?

Comment: Also consider using an existing library, such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: I agree with most of the other comments here, though at first thought it may seem worthwhile to re-write a good portion of the framework in another language there are also lots of good alternatives out there.  I've been a particularly large fan of Processing.org and they have a js library so that would probably be my starting point if I was trying to get something close to AS3 but that primarily works with modern browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience, we can say that writing a DataGrid component is a VERY large undertaking. We've been working on our DataGrid components for 3 years now, and we're STILL adding features. Instead of writing your own ADG like component, you should consider JS frameworks. Below are some:

- DOJO (Excellent framework for RIA Enterprise App Development, and
  Free!)
- Sencha (Pretty good, but commercial)
- JQuery (Very popular, but highly fragmented).

Each of these come with their own grid component. Senchas grid is pretty good, but so are some jquery grids. See this for example:  [Best dynamic JavaScript/JQuery Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677298/best-dynamic-javascript-jquery-grid)

Bottom line, dont reinvent the wheel. There are many excellent paid and free versions out there, pick one that works for you and run with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's really valuable.
Do you know any framework similar to AS3 - i mean idea not code. I'd like choose one witch do not made revolution in my brain and I will can still support my former flex applications :)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am author of Web Atoms JS

Web Atoms JS was built to bring all concepts of Flex, Silverlight and XUL. And each of these technologies used more of XML markup for very high level UI controls. Screens become complex and visualizing them becomes painful when it keeps on changing.

With Web Atoms you will write for less code then any of other frameworks. Web Atoms comes with all basic flex Components & more are coming.

This is a Sample of what all things are possible in Web Atoms JS.

Here is link to documentation.
http://webatomsjs.neurospeech.com/docs

[image]