# Editable Data Grid with Date Time Picker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datagrid, datetimepicker

I've been meaning to implement a Data Grid into my website, where users can dynamically add and edit product information. I have tried jeasyui(see links below) however it does not incorporate a date time picker GUI within the field (I need this because some of the fields that the user has to input includes the shipping date and expiry , and manually writing out the date and time could be cumbersome).

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid12_demo.html

http://jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php

I have used the jeasyui library, and it seems to have worked so far (in terms of the Data Grid), but before I start to write extra code for this, I am looking to get some insight on ways to approach incorporating a Date Time Picker (that checks for date overlaps).

I have tried incorporating jQuery datepicker as a field in the grid, but it was unsuccessful. I am not tied to the jeasyui library, so if you any other libraries you have used that accomplishes this, that would be really helpful.

I currently use PHP for my server side scripting (tied in with a mySQL database) and jQuery for my client side scripting.

Would really appreciate your answers, thanks in advance!

Peter

Comment: jQuery datepicker is good option and it has a rich documentation too..

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: that said [Someone else has already asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677298/best-dynamic-javascript-jquery-grid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Handsontable which is a very easy to use and powerfull datagrid.

Here's the link : http://handsontable.com/

and the link for date field : http://handsontable.com/demo/date.html

Comment: Great! I was wondering if they support time with the date field as well? e.g. http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Being able to edit time would be really nice to have, but this seems promising, I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: when you double-click on a datepicker-cell it open a small calendar to edit the cell.

Comment: I noticed they use the jQuery Datepicker UI Plugin (which I currently use on my website), which works great, but unfortunately it doesn't support time. I kind of need both date and time.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry. Maybe you can use two different fields on the datatable, one for the date and one (or more) for the time ?

Comment: Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/G5ZdR/1/ (hour and min are dropdown)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about having a drop down for hours and minutes as well. It's not as clean as I'd like it to be, but it'll do for now. Thanks for your help!