# DataGrid in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataview

My question might be little strange but I am new to web - based programming. In windows based application, if I need to let the user to edit and view the table then I am using the datagrid. In web - based, there is GridView but it is read only tool. I want to see if there is any tool like this in asp.net. Can you please help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515102.aspx) control, basically, It lets you specify methods to show, update, edit and delete records from your datasource.

There are a lot of examples for it. Here's a nice [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your end users to have a little bit better experience then you should consider the alternative to use a javascript based grid, which is a more modern way to build a grid. Then everything executes smoothly in the web browser without the need to post back and reload the page, and the server will only be called when it's really necessary (loading data, saving data) but not when you change a row when it´s being edited, or if you do incremental searches.

My favorite is the [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples). And here is a cool [Slickgrid example with Async post rendering](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example10-async-post-render.html).

If you choose the server control way (ListView etc) you will have a lot of postbacks every time you sort, change editing mode in cell or edit data.

Look at this question if you want some more [examples of javascript grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677298/best-dynamic-javascript-jquery-grid).